# useEffect appears to be firing without the dependency state being changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a carousel component in my react project - actually, trying to cannibalise an existing carousel written in pure JS so that it works in React using Refs, rather than modifying the DOM directly. I'm having trouble as I attempt to initialise the carousel by marking the first slide in the sequence as the current slide (with className current-slide). I have this operation in a useEffect hook, with {topMovies} as the dependency. {topMovies} is an array of objects passed through to the carousel component as a prop, so useEffect should run when topMovies changes (i.e. loads). This works - upon loading, the first slide in the carousel is given the classname 'current-slide'.

However, the second pieces of code (nextSlide and moveToSlide) is the beginning of a function to select the next slide. The track Ref (which is the container for all of the slides) is passed to the function so that its child element with the className 'current-slide' can be selected and its className removed. This also works - but after a short delay (~1s), the className 'current-slide' re-appears.

```
const Carouselv2 = ({topMovies}) => {

    //Refs

    const trackRef = useRef();
    const nextBtnRef = useRef();
    const prevBtnRef = useRef();
    const navDotsRef = useRef();

    //Initialise carousel upon prop load

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (topMovies && setIsLoading) {
            const slides = Array.from(trackRef.current.children);

            slides[0].classList.add('current-slide'); //Mark first slide as visible

            const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

            const setSlidePosition = (slide, index) => {
                slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + 'px';
            }

            slides.forEach(setSlidePosition); //Arrange slides alongside each other

            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }, [topMovies]);

    //Button functionality

    const moveToSlide = (currentSlide, targetSlide) => {
        //trackRef.current.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + targetSlide.style.left + ')';
        currentSlide.classList.remove('current-slide');
        //targetSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
    }

    const updateDots = () => {

    }

    const responsiveBtns = () => {

    }

    const prevSlide = (e) => {

    }

    const nextSlide = (e) => {
        const currentSlide = trackRef.current.querySelector('.current-slide');
        const nextSlide = trackRef.current.children.nextElementSibling;

        moveToSlide(currentSlide, nextSlide);
    }

    return (
        <div className="carousel">
            <button className="carousel_button carousel_button--left" ref={prevBtnRef}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleLeft} size="xl" style={{ color: "white" }} /></button>
            <div className="carousel_track-container">
                <ul className="carousel_track" ref={trackRef}>
                    {topMovies && topMovies.map((movie) => (
                        <li className="carousel_slide">
                            <img src={movie.image} alt="" />
                            <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button onClick={(e) => nextSlide(e)}className="carousel_button carousel_button--right" ref={nextBtnRef}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleRight} size="xl" style={{ color: "white" }} /></button>
            <div className="carousel_nav" ref={navDotsRef}>
                <button className="carousel_indicator current-slide"></button>
                {topMovies && Array.apply(0, Array(topMovies.length)).map(() => {
                    return <button className="carousel_indicator"></button>
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
```

My first thought was that for some reason, changing the className was causing the useEffect to fire, so I added the if statement with isLoading as a condition. This didn't work, so I don't believe the bug is coming from the useEffect hook.

Pretty stumped by this but this is my first time working with Refs so it is entirely possible that I have missed something extremely obvious. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do not alter the DOM, where it's also possible for React to change it, this will just break React's internal state to DOM state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing DOM created with React, with DOM manipulated with pure Javascript.  You can't do that, it will just break DOM / VDOM relationship.

If your trying to avoid moving the whole component to work the React way, then just use a Ref on an Empty element, the bonus is you get the benefits of the component mounting, and un-mounting.

You can then pretty much copy paste the Javascript bits, just basically place it all inside the `useEffect`.

eg.

Below I create 2 buttons, 1 controlled totally with React, and the other controlled by JS, when you click it just toggles the `pink-button` class.
I've also placed a checkbox to flip the order of buttons to cause a re-render to show how the JS version's state is not corrupted, make sure you use `key` property to let React know it's the same component when you do this.  The main point here is just to show how React will now leave this Button alone, and it's now **totally** your responsibility.  Hopefully this will help show how you can mix React with pure JS.

```js
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#mount');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);

const {createRef, useEffect, useState} = React;

function JSButton() {
  const btnRef = createRef(); 
  useEffect(() => {
     //do everything now from inside this useEffect
     const btn = btnRef.current;     
     btn.innerText = 'This is a Javascript Button';     
     const doClick = () => btn.classList.toggle('pink-button');
     btn.addEventListener('click', doClick);     
     return () => {
       //we can also do any clean-up here
       btn.removeEventListner('click', doClick);
     }
  }, []);
  //only render the button component,
  //don't add any props, classes etc.
  //our JS will be handling it all.
  return <button ref={btnRef}/>;
}

function ReactButton() {
  const [pink, setPink] = useState(false);
  return <button 
    onClick={() => setPink(p => !p)}
    className={pink ? 'pink-button' : ''}>
    React Button
  </button>;
}

function Test() {
  const [jsFirst, setJsFirst] = useState(false);
  return <React.Fragment>
     <input type="checkbox"
       checked={jsFirst}
       onChange={(e) => {
         setJsFirst(e.target.checked);
       }}
     />Js First
     {jsFirst 
       ? <React.Fragment>
           <JSButton key={'js'}/>
           <ReactButton key={'r'}/>
         </React.Fragment>
       : <React.Fragment>
           <ReactButton key={'r'}/>
           <JSButton key={'js'}/>
         </React.Fragment>       
     }
  </React.Fragment>
}

root.render(<Test/>);
```

```css
.pink-button {
  background-color: pink;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was very helpful. I think I was getting confused as to the difference between DOM manipulation via JS and VDOM via React. Back to the drawing board!